# Magic Methods in JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, magic-methods

Are the any *magic(al) methods* under **JavaScript**?

I'm explicitly interested in **setters**, **getters** and **callables** (functions/methods), like those we have in **PHP**: `__set`, `__get` and `__call` && `__callStatic`.

I was googling and searching StackOverflow, but no results.

Please, if anyone is informed - THANKS!