# Javascript Magic Methods

Tags: php, javascript

In php at least in my instance, it is very common to use magic methods -- at least when defining your core classes from which most of everything else will extend from.

Magic methods in php act in a special way from the norm of your regular methods. 
For example one of the most common methods in my book to play with would be the __construct()

The construct is executed every time a class has been loaded. So for instance if you wanted your class to introduce itself you might do something like this:

```
<?php
class Person 
{
    function __construct($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->introduceYourself();
    }

    public function introduceYourself()
    {
        //if $this->name then echo $this->name else echo i dont have name
        echo $this->name ? "hi my name is " . $this->name : "error i dont have name";
    }
}

$dave = new Person('dave');
```

Typically you wouldn't pass something to the construct.

Some other ones that I run across semi-commonly include:

__call() which allows you to change the default way that methods are called. A good example is an override that allows you to get attribute values whenever you use any method that starts with the word get, or setting attribute values whenever a method call starts with the word set.

__get() used as an over loader for class attributes, i don't use but someone  may be interested.

__set() used as an overloader for class attributes, i don't use but someone  may be interested.

__destruct() i also do not use, called as soon as there are no other references to a particular object, or in any order during the shutdown sequence.

**The Question**

Are there magic methods like this inside of javascript?

Are there any hidden gems that a new javascript programmer should be aware of like the ones i've described above for php?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6303896/magic-methods-in-javascript) Also take a look [here for \_\_noSuchMethod\_\_](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/994143/javascript-getter-for-all-properties).

Comment: Possible, but no one bothered to answer or confirm or deny the ones i'm looking for specifically. Or an "emulated" solution.

Answer (score 8):

If by "magic" you mean methods that are called implicitly, Javascript has `toString` and `valueOf`:

```
> foo = {toString: function() { return 'hi' }}
> foo + " there"
"hi there"

> foo = {valueOf: function() { return 100 }}
> foo - 5
95
```

However, there's no standard way to redefine *operators* (what php/python magic methods actually do) in current javascript versions. Harmony (Javascript 6) will include [proxies API](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony%3adirect_proxies) for this kind of work. [This blog entry](http://soft.vub.ac.be/~tvcutsem/proxies/) provides examples and explanations on Proxies, here's a snippet from there that works similar to php's `__get`:

```
var p = Proxy.create({
  get: function(proxy, name) {
    return 'Hello, '+ name;
  }
});
document.write(p.World); // should print 'Hello, World'
```

This already works in Firefox, Chrome support is available if you go to `about:flags` and turn on experimental JavaScript.

Comment: Chrome support is available if you go to `about:flags` and turn on experimental JavaScript :) Note `Proxy` can also do what `__call` does - and in general reflection in JavaScript is very easy to accomplish.

Comment: what will be the alternate of `__iter__` or `__gt__`  (*special method in python*) in **JS**

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript is one of few [prototypal languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype-based_programming), as is Lua. If you are looking for the `constructor`, it is named such (see below). All objects in JavaScript are derived from the [base-`Object`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.2.1).

Virtually all your answers in regard to JavaScripts magic-"methods", have already been included in [Hidden features of JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61088/hidden-features-of-javascript). Visit this StackOverflow site to learn a bit more about JavaScript's syntax and behavior as well as peculiarities, for instance in regard to [comparison operations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators).

Following are some hands-on examples to help you understand the behavior, (and circular references when it comes to serialization of JavaScript objects and importing them in PHP).

```
0 .constructor
function Number() { [native code] }

0 .constructor(10)
>> 10

var myObj = function(){ console.log("I am a new function"); }
>> undefined
myObj.constructor
>> function Function() { [native code] }
myObj.constructor()
>> function anonymous() {}
myObj.prototype.constructor()
>> I am a new function

myObj === myObj.prototype.constructor
>> true

x = new myObj
>> I am a new function
<< myObj {}

x.constructor()
>> I am a new function
<< undefined
```

I wrote an [outline of newer language](http://www.lsauer.com/2012/01/next-javascript-harmony-and-js-17-brief.html) features, but there are many other great resources including SO, and the links already provided by my peers in here.